# How to fix Laravel 5 - The connection was reset/No data received - error in whole app?

Tags: laravel-5

I am receiving connection was reset error in chrome for whole application.

I have emptied storage/framework directory and since then it started throwing connection reset error

Tried to disable opcache and removed app:cache too but both seems not working

Comment: I have checked logged file: /storage/framework/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience there are few possibilities due to these "Connection reset" occurs:

- Sometime blade comment can cause issue, try to avoid multiline and too many blade comments.
- Another reason could be XCache installed on server. In my case it was the issue.

Try to disable and check such caching option.

To disable xcache add following code into your .htaccess file:

```
php_flag xcache.cacher Off
php_flag xcache.size 0
php_flag xcache.stat Off
```